# UBUNTU : NPM EACCES error though I changed folder ownership

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, expo

I have been trying to install expo-cli. Facing several `permission denied` error.
Here are the steps I followed:

1. changed ownership of /usr/lib/node_modules from root to anurag(my_current_user)
2. changed ownership of ~/.npm from root to anurag(my_current_user)
3. changed ownership of ~/.config from root to anurag(my_current_user)
4. changed ownership of ~/home/anurag/.npm from root to anurag(my_current_user)
5. changed ownership of ~/.npm from root to anurag(my_current_user)
6. changed ownership of /usr/bin/node from root to anurag(my_current_user)
7. changed ownership of /usr/bin/nodejs from root to anurag(my_current_user)
8. changed ownership of /usr/bin/node-sass from root to anurag(my_current_user)
9. changed ownership of /usr/bin/expo from root to anurag(my_current_user)
10. changed ownership of /usr/bin/expo-cli from root to anurag(my_current_user)

Here is a snippet of my folder ownership of my expo & expo-cli

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 anurag anurag        40 সেপ্টে 18 19:45  expo -> ../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
lrwxrwxrwx  1 anurag anurag        40 সেপ্টে 18 19:45  expo-cli -> ../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
```

Here is the permission log for node_modules:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   6 anurag anurag  4096 সেপ্টে 19 14:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 142 root   root   12288 সেপ্টে 17 12:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5 anurag anurag  4096 সেপ্টে 18 19:45 expo-cli
drwxr-xr-x   3 anurag anurag  4096 মে    14 12:13 n
drwxr-xr-x   8 anurag anurag  4096 আগস্ট  18 13:57 npm
drwxr-xr-x   3 anurag anurag  4096 সেপ্টে 19 12:24 react-native-cli
```

Here is the error log:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/expo
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/bin/expo'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/bin/expo']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/bin/expo'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: '/usr/bin/expo' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink \'/usr/bin/expo\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/bin/expo' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anurag/.npm/_logs/2019-09-19T08_43_22_377Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't work. But, I found a work around. I solved the problem by changing terminal ownership .

```
sudo -i
```

Then installed successfully.